# D3 SVG I want to highlight an array of elements by mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an SVG container with a number of  elements each containing a rect and some text elements in a horizontal array.

I want to click on one element and drag to one of the others. The first element and element dragged over should highlight - as it would in a normal text editor selection.

at the end I want to know the first and last elements selected so that I can access their data.

I tried this using d3 drag behaviour but: 
1. the intermediate elements can't be highlighted
2. the dragend does not tell me which element was the final one.

Also tried using mouse events but:
1. I can highlight each intermediate item but not easily remove the highlight if the mouse is moved back towards the beginning.
2. if the mouse is moved out of the container I can miss the mouse up events leaving highlighted elements.
3. I still don't really know upon which element I am finishing unless I collect all the mouse over events.

I don't actually want to move the selected elements - just know the first and last one selected.

I created this fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/avowkind/up54b/5/

HTML

```
<svg class='demosvg' version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <rect width="400" height="220"></rect>
    <g id="container" transform="translate(10,10)"></g>
</svg>
```

Javascript

```
var mydata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
/* each box is a group with a rect and text 
   positioned according to the data value
   on drag/drop we want to know the dragged element, and the one it is dropped on.
   we would like to highlight all the intervening elements too.

   Ultimately we just want a result e.g. 2 was dragged to 5
*/
var boxg = d3.select('#container').selectAll('g').data(mydata).enter()
    .append('svg:g')
    .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return "b" + d;
    })
    .attr('transform', function (d, i) {  return "translate(" + d * 50 + ",80)";})
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", function (d, i) {d3.select(this).classed("selected", true); })
        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
            // which element are we over here - to highlight it
            var el = document.elementFromPoint(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
            console.log(el);
        })
        .on("dragend", function (d, i) {
            console.log(d);
            console.log(this);
            console.log(d3.event);
            // turn off all highlights
            d3.selectAll('#container g').classed("selected", false);

        // Which box got dropped on here ? 
    })
);

boxg.append('svg:rect')
    .classed('box', true)
    .attr('width', 40).attr('height', 40);

boxg.append('svg:text')
    .text(function(d,i) { return d; })
    .attr('dx', 15).attr('dy', 20);
```

CSS

```
.demosvg {  fill:silver;}
.box { fill:lightblue;}
text { fill:black;} 
.selected  .box{ fill:gold;}
```

Thanks Andrew

Comment: It sounds like, in addition to the drag behaviour, you would need `mouseover` listeners to tell when you're dragging over a specific element. I would be helpful if you posted some code and told us where exactly you're struggling. As it is, this question is very broad.

Comment: I updated the page to include a full example.